# Set the border for listview images in C# 2008

Tags: c#

im diaplaying the images in the ListView. 
  I want add the border for that images.
  How to do? give me an idea.

im using c# 2008.

Comment: Is it just the images you want a border around? Or is it the whole listview item?

Comment: just border around the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you edit the images before putting them into the ImageList?
Let's say you wanted to add a black border of 4px to the image - you could achieve this with an extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a border to an image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="srcImg"></param>
/// <param name="color">The color of the border</param>
/// <param name="width">The width of the border</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Image AddBorder(this Image srcImg, Color color, int width)
{
    // Create a copy of the image and graphics context
    Image dstImg = srcImg.Clone() as Image;
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dstImg);

    // Create the pen
    Pen pBorder = new Pen(color, width)
    {
        Alignment = PenAlignment.Center
    };

    // Draw
    g.DrawRectangle(pBorder, 0, 0, dstImg.Width, dstImg.Height);

    // Clean up
    pBorder.Dispose();
    g.Save();
    g.Dispose();

    // Return
    return dstImg;
}
```

Then just add the resulting images to your ImageList with something similar to:

```
ImageList1.Images.Add(myImage.AddBorder(Color.Black, 4));
```